# Form to pick a folder content type from a list and create such a foder

Tags: content-type, list-form, edit-form

After a document is uploaded, SP opens a form (EditForm if I am not mistaken) that allows the user to pick the content type of the new document from a list of document content types allowed in the library. I would like to create a form identical to this except it would present the user with a list of folder content types available in the library.

I am going to replace the new folder ribbon button with my own that would open this new form. The user would then be able to select the folder type he/she wants at which point the form would modify the fields accordingly just as is currently done for uploaded documents. The user would fill out the data and submit to create a new folder.

The problem is that I have no idea how to create my own form or how to populate the list of content types dynamically. I plan to use this form in multiple libraries so the content types need to be generated on the fly rather than hard coded.

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I am using SharePoint 2010 and VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to item 1, but the process for folder creation using SPD looks promising in an article here: http://www.getinthesky.com/2012/08/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/

Regarding creating your own forms, you can open SPD and make a copy of the edit or new form to work with and set it to default when achieve desired result. It's not a good idea to modify the original and could get you into trouble if it needs to be restored.

I hope this helps.